# Android Native Video Player Intergration

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

Hey I would like to know is it possible to intergrate the google video player in your app without making the intent calls. I would like to do this because of the different formats the android native video player supports but I don't want the users to have to exit the app even if its only temporarily. Any response would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no possibility to embed another app's view in your own.

I guess you already had a look on [`VideoView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) ?

Comment: thanks for the reply yeah I had. Can you just advise me would it be okay to use the android Native player source code to build another video player which I would customise to suit my needs

Comment: I guess it would, but expect it to be a real challenge as it likely contains native code...